# Extract keyword from a phrase and sum the cost in python - equivalent to sumif in excel

Tags: python, pandas, sumifs

I have a dataframe with sentences that contains a few words and the cost of the sentence. I want to split the sentence into keywords and sum the cost of all the sentences that contain that word.
For example:

| Sentence | Cost |
| --- | --- |
| Hi how are you | 2.5 |
| Hi you there | 5 |

Results:

| Sentence | Cost |
| --- | --- |
| Hi | 7.5 |
| you | 7.5 |
| are | 2.5 |
| how | 2.5 |
| there | 5 |

to split a sentence into keywords I used:

`word["keyword"] = sentence.Sentence.str.split(expand=True).stack()`

but in order to do the sumif, I tried and it doesn't seem to work

````
    word["Cost"]=sentence['Sentence'].str.contains(row["keyword"], na = False) 
    ['cost'].sum()```

Can you think of a way to make it work?
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Full Code**

```
(df.assign(Sentence=df['Sentence'].str.split(' '))
   .explode('Sentence')
   .groupby('Sentence').sum())
```

output:

```
        Cost
Sentence    
Hi      7.5
are     2.5
how     2.5
there   5.0
you     7.5
```

---

**Step1**

split words in `Sentence column`

```
df.assign(Sentence=df['Sentence'].str.split(' '))
```

output:

```
    Sentence            Cost
0   [Hi, how, are, you] 2.5
1   [Hi, you, there]    5.0
```

**Step2**

explode result of step1

```
df.assign(Sentence=df['Sentence'].str.split(' ')).explode('Sentence')
```

output:

```
    Sentence    Cost
0   Hi          2.5
0   how         2.5
0   are         2.5
0   you         2.5
1   Hi          5.0
1   you         5.0
1   there       5.0
```

**Step3**

groupby result of step2.
it is same with full code

Answer (score 0):

`['cost']` is not declared - it is just incorrect syntax. the variable is called `word`.

if you want to add up all content in `word` you could do it that way:

```
costs = 0
for sentence, cost in word.items():
    costs += cost
```

depending on the data type of `cost` you would have to add a conversion from `str` to `float` maybe.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient approach would be to avoid using pandas and rely on pure python (pandas is not very efficient when strings operations are used):

```
d = {}
for s, c in zip(df['Sentence'], df['Cost']):
    for word in s.split():
        d[word] = d.get(word, 0) + c

out = pd.DataFrame({'Sentence': out.keys(), 'Cost': out.values()})

# or as Series:
# out = pd.Series(d)
```

Output:

```
  Sentence  Cost
0       Hi   7.5
1      how   2.5
2      are   2.5
3      you   7.5
4    there   5.0
```

Reproducible input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Sentence': ['Hi how are you', 'Hi you there'],
                   'Cost': [2.5, 5.0]})
```